# excluding javaclasses in java, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, export, war

I've a dynamic web project which consists multiple webservices inside. I want to export this project as a war file but I don't want to export all the webservices but only the ones I want. How can I do that? I excluded the java classes from the build path but that didn't work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ant to do your builds.
Set up your targets and exclusions as required.
http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/989631/Building-with-Ant-Introduction.htm

Think you can use Maven too, but I'm not familiar with it

Comment: can you give an example ant script to build a project? I mean , can you give a referance link 'cuz I couldn't find one

Answer (score 0):

Does right-click on the java class(es) -> Build path -> Exclude help?

I know it will remove it from build, but haven't tried it on the WAR file export.

otherwise, as Steve suggested, using ANT is your best bet.

Comment: yes, it does remove from the build but doesn't remove from the war.

Comment: @Samet I think it's best for you to go with a simple ANT script. The benefit also is that you do not have to start eclipse every time you want a build.